# how to navigate to next screen after successful of paytm payment transaction. in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation, payment, paytm

I am integrating paytm transaction in react native API. and I have successfully integrated it. I am able to do successful transaction. but after transaction successful. some data from API is showing over there. like this = "[{"message":"success","is_payment_done":"Y"}]". but the problem is how can I navigate to next which I want to display after successful transaction.

here is my code

```
export default class payment extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      order_id: "",
      mid: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      tranxToken: "",
      amount: "20",
      // callbackUrl:
      //   "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=TESTORDER_1",
      isStaging: true,
      appInvokeRestricted: true,
    };
  }

  call_api = () => {
    fetch("https://xxxxxxx.in/App_API_CI/xxxxxxxxxx", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },

      body: JSON.stringify([
        {
          mobile_no: "xxxxxxxxx",
          user_id: "xx",
          patient_name: "xxxxxxx",
        },
      ]),
    })
      .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())

      .then((response) => {
        console.log(
          "this checksum api esponse" +
            JSON.stringify(response[0].data.txnToken)
        );

        this.setState({ order_id: response[0].data.order_id });
        this.setState({ tranxToken: response[0].data.txnToken });

        this.handleTransaction();
      });
  };

  handleTransaction = () => {
    AllInOneSDKManager.startTransaction(
      this.state.order_id,
      this.state.mid,
      this.state.tranxToken,
      this.state.amount,
      "https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=" +
        this.state.order_id,
      this.state.isStaging,
      this.state.appInvokeRestricted
    )

      .then((result) => {
        () => console.log(result);
        //AsyncStorage.setItem("is_payment_done", "Y");
        this.props.navigation.navigate("MyDrawerRP");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        Toast.show("Something went wrong");
      });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ alignSelf: "center", flex: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this.call_api}
          style={{
            height: 90,
            width: width / 1.2,
            backgroundColor: "#7DF8F8",
            justifyContent: "center",
            elevation: 20,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ alignSelf: "center", fontSize: 35, color: "#000080" }}>
            PAY 20/-
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("MyDrawerRP");
```

this line should do your navigation. You sure your code gets here? i.e. is transaction completes successfully? If so, check if 'MyDrawerRP' is added to your navigator.

Comment: but in my code where should I put that line. bcoz when i put it in .then(result) block then its not working

Comment: navigation code is in correct location. my guess the problem is (1) either your code does not get to `.then(result)` block or (2) `MyDrawerRP` screen isn't configured correctly. to verify (1) - add `console.log()` to `then` block. for (2) - check if `MyDrawerRP` is added to the navigator. perhaps there are any errors in the log?

Comment: ok I got it there is nothing print in .then(result) block. so the problem with code I think ..

Comment: But why .then(result) block is not executing..? whats the problem in code

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove ()=> after fetching result and test if you are able to get the result in log and proceed with the check on navigating

```
.then((result) => {
    () => console.log(result);    //remove () => here
    //AsyncStorage.setItem("is_payment_done", "Y");
    this.props.navigation.navigate("MyDrawerRP");
  })
```

Comment: adding this () => wont print your console.log(result); If removing ()=> this still doesnt work then you should check the error received in catch block

Comment: no error is also not coming just server API response is printing on screen like message : success. is payment done : Y

Comment: I think after payment successful its going to callbackURL . so how do I navigate to screen not callbacURL.

Comment: check if it is entering handleTransaction() if yes then wrap the complete code inside handleTransaction in try catch and check if there is some issue within it else debug and see if that executes you should definitely get the result or the error for startTransaction